# Checking for empty textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Im trying to Create a method that can look at all text boxes in my program and tell me when the next blank one is so far. this is what i have come up with and cannot get it to work

```
    public void CheckBox()
    {
        string[] itemBoxArray = new string[] { "itemBox1", "itemBox2", "itemBox3", "itemBox4", "itemBox5", "itemBox6", 
            "itemBox7", "itemBox8", "itemBox9", "itemBox10","itemBox11","itemBox12","itemBox13","itemBox14","itemBox15","itemBox16",};
        for (int i = 0; i < itemBoxArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (itemBoxArray[i] == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(" " + itemBoxArray[i] + " Is empty");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Item Box is full");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create array of `TextBox` like below

```
    public void CheckBox()
    {
        TextBox[] itemBoxArray = new TextBox[] { itemBox1, itemBox2, ........};
        for (int i = 0; i < itemBoxArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(itemBoxArray[i].Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(" " + itemBoxArray[i].Name + " Is empty");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Item Box is full");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to find the first `TextBox` that has an empty `Text` value:

```
var emptyTextBox = Controls.OfType<TextBox>().First(x => x.Text == string.Empty);

MessageBox.Show(string.Format(" {0} Is empty", emptyTextBox.Name));
```

You'll probably have to beef this up a bit.

- It'll fail if no `TextBox` is empty. Use `FirstOrDefault` and test for `null` if that's a concern.
- Also, it'll fail to find `TextBox` controls inside of a `GroupBox` or `Panel`. That may not matter depending on how your form is designed.

If you only have a set number of `TextBox` controls to check for, your code will work with a little adjustment, but if you're going to keep adding more `TextBox`es, it's going to be a pain to maintain.

Comment: Would i have to add this into my if function or would this be the take over both my for loop and if statement